# IE browser does not support font face "Gotham"

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have use Gothma font for my website but its not support in any IE browser, 
below is my css

```
    /* FONT FACE */
@font-face{font-family: Gotham Book;src: url(fonts/Gotham-Book.otf);}
@font-face{font-family: Gotham Bold;src: url(fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf);}
@font-face{font-family: Gotham Light;src: url(fonts/Gotham-Light.otf);}
@font-face{font-family: Gotham Medium;src: url(fonts/Gotham-Medium.otf);}
```

Comment: when you say... any IE browser... do you mean ALL of them?

Comment: You are missing the quotes around `Gotham Book`,`Gotham BoldGotham Light`, and `Gotham Medium`. They are necessary because of the space character in the name.

Comment: @HerrSerker, no, quotation marks not needed; check CSS specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [**The New Bulletproof Fontface Syntax**](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

```
    @font-face {

        font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
        src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
             url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
             url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
             url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

**Browser compatibility:**

> Safari 5.03, IE 6-9, Firefox 3.6-4, Chrome 8, iOS 3.2-4.2, Android 2.2-2.3, Opera 11

To generate your font-kit you should use [**fontsquirrel**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: if I am useing fontsquirrel and adding gotham font a error shows Gotham font is blacklisted..how do I add also its not support in IE10 and 11 version

Comment: @design4web If it is blacklisted, then it means that it's a commercial font, and you need to buy a license if you want to use it on the web - http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/